# Payment Proposal functionality in AX 2009

Tags: axapta, x++, microsoft-dynamics, ax

When we go to Payment Journal/Lines / Create Payment Proposal - Select the vendor and click ok , it now creates the Open Transaction lines in the top part of the form and a single line with the amount totalled in the Payment Proposal(lower part of the form).

But i dont want the amount to be totalled , instead it should display the corresponding amount in the open Transaction Part(header part).

Can anyone please let me know how do we that?

Answer (score 1):

The lower part of the payment proposal shows you the payment amounts, while the upper part shows you the transactions covered by each payment.

The system tries to lower the number of payments, as many banks charge you pr. payment.

On the "Methods of payment" (Accounts Payable / Setup / Payment / Methods of payment) you can control how the transactions are summed up. The field Period lets you choose between Invoice, Date, Week and Total.

Through "Payment attributes", also on Methods of payment, you can select certain attributes that will exclude the transaction from a given payment sum.